# What does/can BIOS exactly limit?

Tags: cpu, bios, processor-socket

We all know, that BIOS might limit a lot of things, but what are those? I'm about to buy a new CPU, but this time it is going to be a QuadCore i7, so can BIOS limit also max cores and threads and things like that? Take this as a sub-question, the prior one is what can BIOS limit, I expect it to be much around limits of the motherboard components, if is out there someone who has intel about this, tell me please, how may bios limitate new CPUs etc. Sorry for making the question so „weird“, but I'm 13 and not from England, so I can't build proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits of the BIOS arent that big, its more small things and features, like the number of primary partitions or the max size of your boot partition etc.
It doesn't affect your cpu speed or limit max cores, and im pretty sure you would have UEFI (more modern BIOS)because if you are buying an i-7 i would assume you are also buying a modern motherboard.
To answer your question simply, No the BIOS wont limit your cpu in any way, and would not affect your PC's preformance.

Comment: Well, nah, I'm upgrading 2012 laptop so no uefi for me, but thanks for your answear!